# SSCrypto/OpenSSL to C# Crypto

Tags: c#, .net, cocoa, encryption, openssl

Has anyone been able to use the SSCrypto Framework for Cocoa to encrypt text and then decrypt it in C#/.NET ? Or can someone offer some guidance?

I'm pretty sure my issue has to do with getting the crypto settings correct but I am far from fluent in Cocoa so I can't really tell what settings are being used in the library. However my attempt at deciphering it seems like md5 hashing, CBC mode, padding with zeros and I have no idea if the IV is set or not...

My C# code looks like this:

```
        public static string Decrypt( string toDecrypt, string key, bool useHashing )
    {
        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String( toDecrypt );

        if( useHashing )
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash( UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( key ) );
            hashmd5.Clear();
        }
        else
            keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( key );

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock( toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length );

        tdes.Clear();

        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString( resultArray );
    }
```

When I run encryption on the Cocoa side I get the encrypted text:

UMldOZh8sBnHAbfN6E/9KfS1VyWAa7RN

but that won't decrypt on the C# side with the same key.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't really know .NET that well, can you post your Cocoa code too? It might make it easier for people well versed in one or the other to help you out...

Answer (score 2):

You could use OpenSSL directly in C# with the [OpenSSL.NET](http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net) wrapper!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to watch out for:

1- Make sure that you're interpreting the key and data strings correctly. For example, is the key encoded in ASCII instead of UTF8? Does it perhaps represented in binhex format instead?

2- You're not initializing the IV (Initialization Vector) before decrypting. It needs to match the IV you're using to encrypt on the Cocoa side.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, OpenSSL uses what MS calls PKCS7 padding (though OpenSSL refers to it as PKCS5, and I'm not enough of a standards wonk to care why).

Answer (score 0):

One of the classic issues in moving data back and forth from Mac to PC is byte ordering. You didn't say what the execution platform is for the Cocoa code, but that's something to look out for, especially if it's a PowerPC Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There could be something to do with endianness,

Try to call Array.Reverse before decryption.

```
var reversedArr = Array.Reverse(toEncrytArray)
byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock( reversedArr, 0, reversedArr.Length );
```

Comment: Why would you only do that on the receiving side? The sending side (the Mac) could also be an Intel machine. The correct place to do byte-swapping is either on the Mac (use little-endian over the wire) or both (use big-endian, aka network byte order, over the wire).

Answer (score 0):

You should really post the Cocoa code, too, to give us a chance to find your problem.

But there are some hints hidden in what you have posted:

Decrypting PyPqLI/d18Q= (base64) with the key and iv gives "97737D09E48B0202" (hex). This looks like the plaintext "97737D09E48B" with PKCS7-padding. So I would start by changing the .NET code to use PaddingMode.PKCS7 and look closely at where you pass the plaintext to the Cocoa code.